# Lasso Regression predicting average values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I'm trying to use Lasso regression to predict non-binary categorical output:

First I read in the data using pandas, then I mean impute missing values and standardize the data using StandardScaler(). I split my data into train and test, and training data further into train and validation and then train the model for different alphas. I calculate the mean squared error between y_predicted and y_validated and the best model selected is always the model that predicts all values as the mean or close to the mean output.

```
X = pd.read_csv(X_path)
y = pd.read_csv(y_path)

X = X.fillna(X.mean())

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=77)
sc=StandardScaler()

X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

X_train_,X_validate,y_train_,y_validate = train_test_split(X_train,y_train,test_size=0.2,random_state=77)
alphas=np.linspace(-1,1,50)

mse=np.zeros(len(alphas))

for i in range(0,len(alphas)):
     lasso_reg = lasso(alpha=alphas[i])
     lasso_reg.fit(X_train_,y_train_)

     y_pred = lasso.predict(X_validate)
     mse[i] = mean_squared_error(y_pred,y_validate)
```

I've tried changing the alphas and also standardizing within lasso but same results.
Any ideas what might be wrong or any suggestions which evaluation metric would be more suitable?

My data is bit unbalanced, it is approximately normally distributed between 20-100 where most of the data lies between 40-65. Could that be causing the problem?